# Error logging into website with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know that there are many questions with the same problem but none of them have helped me.
This is my script. I am trying to login into the willhaben website. I am from austria that is why I am using willhaben.at
Python version 3.5.4
Selenium version 3.8.0
PhantomJS version 2.1

```
#need some of the libraries for later code
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import sys
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

input("If ready press 'enter'")

loginurl = 'https://www.willhaben.at/iad/?islogout=true&logoff.y=10'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\laure\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options, service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])


USERNAME = 'notgonnagiveit :)'
PASSWORD = 'notgonnagiveit'

driver.get(loginurl)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]'))
    )

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')

password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
username.send_keys(USERNAME)

driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
  File "D:\OneDrive\Dokumente\Willhaben\Willhaben.py", line 73, in <module>
    password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 352, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use :

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']")
```

Comment: And what shall I use instead of the " * "  for buttons

Comment: No, lets get granular. We would search the smallest area of the `DOM` to search for the elements. We won't include `*` until and unless we are directionless.

Comment: (I get the same error from the original question)
    >>> editbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn icon-icon_bearbeiten status-expired'][@type='button']")
    >>> editbutton.click()

Comment: Exactly which element?

Comment: `//input[@class='btn icon-icon_bearbeiten status-expired'][@type='button']` doesnot identifies any `WebElement` on the `Web Page`. If you are looking to click on the **`Login`** button, that is within a `<button>` tag and you must be using **`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-wh-primary' and @id='wh-login-btn']")`**

Comment: No this is a different button. It has a **<a>** tag and is **type=button**. The login button worked. Has no problem

Comment: Can you raise a new question please to look into that :)

Comment: Unable to access `https://www.willhaben.at/iad/myprofile/adadministration/showlist?page=6` without logging in through credentials :)

Comment: I don't have to log in again do i?. or do you want to look into the website's html

Comment: Without credentials we can't access `https://www.willhaben.at/iad/myprofile/adadministration/show‌​list?page=6` to get the `WebElement` **"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='btn icon-icon_bearbeiten status-expired'][@type='button']"**

Comment: Copy the formatted text `HTML` of that concerned `WebElement`  within the new question for our reference.

Comment: it's in the new question @DebanjanB